# Hide/Show show function on PHP Loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using PHP Loop to make a template of a list of essays. But, I need the content to be hidden until it been clicked. The problem is, it only affected the first content. Even I clicked on the other content. It reacts to the first content. Any method to make it individually?

```
<script>
   function contentRead() {
    var x = document.getElementById("content");
     if (x.style.display === "block") {
         x.style.display = "none";
     } else {
         x.style.display = "block";}
   }   
</script>

<div class="Book">
 <?php foreach($blog as $row) : ?>
  <div class="chapter" onclick="contentRead()">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <h2 class="title"><?= $row ["title"];?></h2>
    <p class="essay" id="content" style="display:none"><?= $row ["content"];?></p>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `id` attributes need to be unique in a document. You have multiple `id="content"` there.

Comment: The `<script>` stuff should be outside of the loop

Comment: I place it outside the loop, but the result still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `<script>` outside of the loop and have it accept an ID as the first parameter so that it can be reused. Then, in your loop, give each item a unique ID. A common way to do this is just keep incrementing a variable.

```php
<?php

$blog = [
    [
        'title' => 'Alpha',
        'content' => 'Alpha content',
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Beta',
        'content' => 'Beta content',
    ],
];

$idx = 0;
?>
<script>
    function contentRead(id) {
        var x = document.getElementById(id);
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="content">
    <?php foreach ($blog as $row) : ?>
        <?php $id = 'content-' . $idx++; ?>
        <div class="chapter" onclick="contentRead('<?php echo $id; ?>')">
            <div class="cover"></div>
            <h2 class="title"><?= $row ["title"]; ?></h2>
            <p class="essay" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display:none"><?php echo $row ["content"]; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```